# How to use CalendarApp.getCalendarById on a range

Tags: google-apps-script

Still very green behind the ears when it comes to google script, but oh so excited by the possibilities it dangles in front of me.

**Use case**: to pull google calendar appointments from about 70 email addresses (list is a factor of staffing situation) and then consolidate them on a google sheet.

**Problem**: works fine when I use a static team calendar (which however goes unused by 69 colleagues of mine) or a single email address (meaning permission sets are not the issue). Just can't seem to get getCalendarById to work when I define a range.

This is where I'm at:

**Works:**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxx-XxqMb4E3LW2U1qoGZ6I");
var ss_raw = ss.getSheetByName("Raw");
var ss_time = ss.getSheetByName("Time");
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxx.com_nfl666rclt5jkhfeb5i6n1f17s@group.calendar.google.com");
...
```

**Does not work ("null values"):**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxx-XxqMb4E3LW2U1qoGZ6I");
var ss_raw = ss.getSheetByName("Raw");
var ss_time = ss.getSheetByName("Time");
var ss_emails = ss.getSheetByName("Emails");
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(ss_emails.getRange(A1:A100).getValues);
...
```

Tried using var-for, but can't seem to get it to work that way either.

Any ideas? Appreciate the help!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why does `getCalendarById(ss_emails.getRange(A1:A100).getValues);` not work?

Because `getCalendarById()` expects a single ID, why you are passing it a 2-D array containing 100 IDs.

I assume, you want to retrieve all of the calendars to further work with them (e.g. pulling all events).

To do so, you need to implement a loop and iterate through all IDs individually.

Mind that `getValues()` (don't forget the brackets!) returns you a 2D array of values, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) - even if your values are contained in a single row.

So first, you need to reduce the nested 2D array to a 1D array  -e.g. by specifying `var values=ss_emails.getRange("A1:A100").getValues()[0]`.

And second, as already mentioned, loop through the 1D array of calendar IDs.

Sample:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxx-XxqMb4E3LW2U1qoGZ6I");
var ss_raw = ss.getSheetByName("Raw");
var ss_time = ss.getSheetByName("Time");
var ss_emails = ss.getSheetByName("Emails");
var values = ss_emails.getRange(A1:A100).getValues()[0];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(values[i]);
  ...
  }
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That does the trick for all calendars I'm already subscribed to. Knowing my colleagues, subscribing to calendars will be a bridge too far. Tried to auto-subscribe if _calendar_ is null. 
`var values = ss_emails.getRange("A1:100").getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(values[i]);
  if(calendar == null){
  //user may not have access, auto-subscribe them.
  calendar = CalendarApp.subscribeToCalendar(calendar,{hidden:true,selected:false});
  }};`
=> Execution failed: We're sorry, a server error occurred. 
O-o'

Comment: Done :) Any thoughts as to the auto-subscription? The whole concept kinda stands or falls with that :s

Comment: The autosubscribe is not as trivial as it might seem since recently Google changed its security policy, so after adding someone to a calendar, the person has to confirm it first. This is why I recommend you to post a separate question about it.